# How Can I populate a JTable from an excel file, as long as there is more than 1 matching element in my Array List? [Java]

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm having a problem populating a JTable from an excel file. Here is the operation, I will search, lets say "Line 1", there are 2 cells matching this value, if there is a match, I would like to pull the row and insert it into my JTable. I was able to get this working, however, this only creates one row for the first matching value, when i click on search button again, it will replace  the row, with a new row, if there was more than 1 match.

I would the jtable to add both rows in the same table, rather one by one. I attached what I have so far.

Thank You in advanced.

```
try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                        new File("S:\\Tester Support\\0LineTester Database\\Audit\\LASAudit.xlsx"));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                for (Row row : sheet) {
                    for (Cell cell : row) {
                        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(LinNum_Text.getText())) {
                                int rowNum = row.getRowNum();

                                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

                                int col_0 = 0;
                                String val_0 = r.getCell(col_0).getStringCellValue();
                                int col_1 = 1;
                                String val_1 = r.getCell(col_1).getStringCellValue();
                                int col_2 = 2;
                                String val_2 = r.getCell(col_2).getStringCellValue();
                                int col_3 = 3;
                                String val_3 = r.getCell(col_3).getStringCellValue();

                                model.addColumn("ID", new Object[] { val_0 });
                                model.addColumn("Date", new Object[] { val_1 });
                                model.addColumn("Auditor Name", new Object[] { val_2 });
                                model.addColumn("Line #", new Object[] { val_3 });

                                table = new JTable(model);
                                table.setVisible(true);

                                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
                                scrollPane.setBounds(10, 278, 670, 303);
                                contentPane.add(scrollPane);
                                scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Would you be able to include the import statements & jar files that we'd need to test it plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was able to get this working, however, this only creates one row for the first matching value,

That is because in your "looping code" you create a new JTable each time.

Instead you want to create the table once and add data to your TableModel inside the loop. So the structure of your code should be something like:

```
String[] columnNames = { "Id", "Date", ... };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for (...)
{
    ...

    if (matched row found)
    {
        ...

        Object[] row = { val_0, val_1, ...};
        model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
...
```

Comment: `updated my code above` - 1) post the code properly formatted if you want people to take the time to read the code. 2) that is not what I suggested. Why do you have a loop to assign a value to "value_0"? It will only ever contain a single value (not 4 separate values). This is basic Java.

Answer (score 0):

With camickr's help I got this to work. Here is the final code.

```
try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                            new File("S:\\Tester Support\\0LineTester Database\\Audit\\LASAudit.xlsx"));
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);



                                        String[] columnNames = {"Id","Date","Auditor Name","Line Number"};
                                        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

                                        JTable table = new JTable(model);
                    table.setVisible(true);

                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
                    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 278, 670, 303);
                    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

                    for (Row row : sheet) {
                        for (Cell cell : row) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(Spec_Text.getText())) {
                                    int rowNum = row.getRowNum();
                                    Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

                                    int col_0 = 0;
                                    String val_0 = r.getCell(col_0).getStringCellValue();
                                    int col_1 = 1;
                                    String val_1 = r.getCell(col_1).getStringCellValue();
                                    int col_2 = 2;
                                    String val_2 = r.getCell(col_2).getStringCellValue();
                                    int col_3 = 3;
                                    String val_3 = r.getCell(col_3).getStringCellValue();

                                                                        Object[] ROWS = { val_0, val_1, val_2,val_3};
                                                                        model.addRow( ROWS );

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```